# TextInput value is not updated

Tags: react-native

Im using a function to update a TextInput value on onChangeText event. If I console log the value after the state update in the function, it prints the updated value, but it is not showing the updated value in the input. *errorMessages* and *input* are states (useState hook).Any idea on how to fix this?

**I'm using this to create the useState hooks:**

```
const errors = {
    name: null,
    // more fields
};

const inputs = {
    name: '',
    // more fields
};

const [input, setInput] = useState(inputs);
const [errorMessages, setErrorMessages] = useState(errors);
```

**Here is the text input:**

```
<Input
   label={'Name'}
   style={styles.input}
   blurOnSubmit
   autoCapitalize={'none'}
   autoCorrect={false}
   value={input['name']}
   onChangeText={value => handleInput('name', value)}
/>
```

**Here are the functions to update the value:**

```
const handleError = (field, value) => {
    const errors = errorMessages;
    errors[field] = validate(field, value);
    setErrorMessages(errors);
};

const handleField = (field, value) => {
    console.log('input before: ' + input[field]) // prints the previous value correctly
    const updateData = input;
    updateData[field] += value;
    setInput(updateData);
    console.log('input after: ' + input[field]) // prints the updated value correctly
};

const handleInput = (field, value) => {
    handleError(field, value);
    handleField(field, value);
};
```

Comment: try to use only "=" at line updateData[field] += value;

Comment: Yes, thats correct. But since the input is not getting its value updated, the value passed to the function is only the last key pressed. When the error is fixed, I must change it for =

Comment: and then, try another thing: const updateData = { ...input }, to create another object

Comment: It worked! Creating a new object did the trick, thank you so much. Want to write an answer so I mark it as solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new object before update:

```
const handleError = (field, value) => {
    const errors = { ...errorMessages };
```

and

```
const handleField = (field, value) => {
    const updateData = { ...input };
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your trying to update integer value to string state, then you have to try following way, when ever you update integer value to string state then you have to use

```
    const [text,setText] = useState('')
    setText(100)
    instead you use 
    setText(`100`)
```

then only it will take integer as string. what is strange thing is you will not getting any error at all that why hard to know by beginner